# Do indexes interfere with each other in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, indexing

I have a table with 3 columns. This table contains many raws (millions). When I select rows from the table I frequently use the following `where` clauses:

```
where column2=value1 and column3=value2
where column1=value
```

To speed up the `select` query I want to declare column1 and column2 as indexes. My questions is **if declaring the second column as an index will not reduce the positive effect of declaring the first column as index**.

I also would like to ask if declaring the second column as index will speed up the queries of this type: `where column2=value1 and column3=value2`.

**ADDED**
The `column1`, `column2`, and `column3` are `entity`, `attribute`, `value`. It's very general. As entities I use person, movies, cities, countries and so on. Attributes are things like: "located in", "date of birth", "produced by".

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us more about your table. `column1`, `column2`, `column3` makes us have to guess what the constraints are.

Comment: @Theo, I have updated my question by adding the requested information.

Comment: Looks to me like you could have a primary key on the `entity,attribute` combination, but that is if entity/attribute combinations don't have multiple values. It's ok to not have a primary key, but sometimes it can be useful to have one even if it spans all columns, since it guards against inserting duplicate rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create indexes that support your queries. In this case you want to create an index on `column2,column3` together (not two separate indexes, but *one* index for the combination of columns) to support the first query, and another on `column1` to support the second query. More generally, if a query uses a set of columns, adding an index for all those columns will speed it up (although there are many exceptions, of course).

An index on `column2` would speed up the query `column2=value1 and column1=value2`, and so would an index on `column2,column3` (the important thing is that `column2` is the first column in the index).

When working with indexes the `EXPLAIN` keyword is very useful. Prefix your queries with `EXPLAIN` (e.g. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table`) to get a description of how the database is going to perform your query. It will tell you if it's going to use an index, and in that case which.

Comment: You mean that I need to put indexes on all three columns?

Comment: @Roman I've updated my answer, hopefully it's more clear on that point now. In short: no, you should create two indexes, one with `column2,column3` (that is _one_ index with _two_ columns) and one with `column1`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is good to know that I can use several columns to define one index. By the way, can I declare column2 as an index if I already use `column2,column3` as one index?

Comment: A column can be part of many indexes, there will be no "interference". However, if `column2` is already the first column of another index, adding a separate index with only `column2` is unnecessary. If a column is the first column in a multi-column index that index can be used in queries with only that column, this goes for combinations of columns too. In other words, the index `a,b,c` can be used in queries with only `a`, with only `a` and `b` or with queries with `a`, `b`, and `c`. It cannot be used in queries without `a`, for example `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like neither of your plans are going to work. Based on both of the where clauses I would suggest having the **primary key** on `column1` and a second index `column2,column3`. This would speed up both of your queries.

Comment: I cannot put primary key on the first column because values in the first column are not unique.

Comment: Doesn't matter, than simply add another index. You'd end up with two new indexes ("column1" and "column2,column3").

Comment: But as far as I know "a primary key is used to uniquely identify each row in a table." In my case different rows can have the same value of the first column. Why it is not sufficient to put index on the first column? Why additionally to that I need to make it "primary key"?

Comment: If there is any combination of rows that will always uniquely identify a row, use that combination as primary key. It could just as well be the combination `column2,column3` that is the primary key (more than one column can be part of an index).

Comment: You don't have to have a primary key, in fact you don't have to have any index at all. Good database design - on the other hand - simply requires you to have some sort of "unique index", be it a single column or multiple columns. The lacking of possible primary key candidates indicates poor database design and will cost you performance once the database grows beyond a certain point.

Comment: @Theo and @aefxx, only values in three columns uniquely identify my rows (there are no identical rows). Any other combination of rows is not unique.